# FFmpeg: Looping an video/audio stream to YouTube Live

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, video-streaming

I'm using this script to stream a 30s `.mp4` video file with a 2min audio track in `.mp3` format:

```
#! /bin/bash

VBR="1500k"
FPS="30"
QUAL="ultrafast"
YOUTUBE_URL=" rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2"
YOUTUBE_KEY="**********"
VIDEO_SOURCE="test_video_4.mp4"
AUDIO_SOURCE="test_audio_3.mp3"
AUDIO_ENCODER="aac"

ffmpeg \
 -stream_loop -1 \
 -re \
 -i "$VIDEO_SOURCE" \
 -thread_queue_size 512 \
 -i "$AUDIO_SOURCE" \
 -c:v libx264 -preset $QUAL -r $FPS -g $(($FPS *2)) -b:v $VBR \
 -c:a $AUDIO_ENCODER -threads 6 -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -bufsize 512k -pix_fmt yuv420p \
 -fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 50000 \
 -f flv $YOUTUBE_URL/$YOUTUBE_KEY
```

Both the audio and the video get played correctly the first time, with the video looping while the audio playback is completed (since it's shorter). The only problem is that ***the audio loop does not work*** and as soon the audio completes the first time the stream simply stops.

Here's the log:

> ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
> built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)
> configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1_4
> --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack   libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100   libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100   libavformat    58. 45.100 /
> 58. 45.100   libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100   libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100   libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0   libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100   libswresample   3.  7.100 /
> 3.  7.100   libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100 Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test_video_4.mp4':   Metadata:
> major_brand     : mp42
> minor_version   : 1
> compatible_brands: isommp41mp42
> creation_time   : 2020-11-27T18:38:02.000000Z   Duration: 00:00:39.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 12081 kb/s
> Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 12033
> kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 48k tbc (default)
> Metadata:
> creation_time   : 2020-11-27T18:38:02.000000Z
> handler_name    : Core Media Video Input #1, mp3, from 'test_audio_3.mp3':   Metadata:
> genre           : Cinematic
> album           : YouTube Audio Library
> title           : Test Title
> artist          : Test Artist   Duration: 00:02:12.21, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 320 kb/s
> Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
> Metadata:
> encoder         : LAME3.99r Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))   Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (mp3 (mp3float) -> aac (native)) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help [libx264 @
> 0x7fa825031600] VBV maxrate unspecified, assuming CBR [libx264 @
> 0x7fa825031600] using SAR=1/1 [libx264 @ 0x7fa825031600] using cpu
> capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2 [libx264 @
> 0x7fa825031600] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
> [libx264 @ 0x7fa825031600] 264 - core 161 r3027 4121277 - H.264/MPEG-4
> AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html -
> options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1
> psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0
> 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0
> threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1
> interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0
> keyint=60 keyint_min=6 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=0
> rc=cbr mbtree=0 bitrate=1500 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69
> qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=1500 vbv_bufsize=512 nal_hrd=none filler=0
> ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0 Output #0, flv, to
> 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/*****':
> Metadata:
> major_brand     : mp42
> minor_version   : 1
> compatible_brands: isommp41mp42
> encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
> Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 1500 kb/s,
> 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
> Metadata:
> creation_time   : 2020-11-27T18:38:02.000000Z
> handler_name    : Core Media Video
> encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libx264
> Side data:
> cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/1500000 buffer size: 512000 vbv_delay: N/A
> Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
> Metadata:
> encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 aac Larger timestamp than 24-bit: 0xffff9b44kB time=00:02:37.43 bitrate=1292.6kbits/s
> speed=0.995x     [flv @ 0x7fa825032800] Failed to update header with
> correct duration. [flv @ 0x7fa825032800] Failed to update header with
> correct filesize. frame= 3790 fps= 24 q=-1.0 Lsize=   24962kB
> time=00:02:38.03 bitrate=1294.0kbits/s speed=0.997x     video:22719kB
> audio:2081kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
> overhead: 0.656017% [libx264 @ 0x7fa825031600] frame I:64    Avg
> QP:36.43  size: 38436 [libx264 @ 0x7fa825031600] frame P:3726  Avg
> QP:28.61  size:  5583 [libx264 @ 0x7fa825031600] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%
> 0.0%  0.0% [libx264 @ 0x7fa825031600] mb P  I16..4:  3.3%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 13.6%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:83.1% [libx264 @
> 0x7fa825031600] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 57.8% 71.6% 47.8% inter: 6.0%
> 7.1% 2.1% [libx264 @ 0x7fa825031600] i16 v,h,dc,p: 21% 39% 23% 18% [libx264 @ 0x7fa825031600] i8c dc,h,v,p: 36% 38% 16% 10% [libx264 @
> 0x7fa825031600] kb/s:1177.39 [aac @ 0x7fa82502d800] Qavg: 179.328
> Exiting normally, received signal 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop the audio too:

```
ffmpeg \
 -stream_loop -1 \
 -re \
 -i "$VIDEO_SOURCE" \
 -thread_queue_size 512 \
 -stream_loop -1 \
 -re \
 -i "$AUDIO_SOURCE" \
 -c:v libx264 -preset $QUAL -r $FPS -g $(($FPS *2)) -b:v $VBR -bufsize 3000k -maxrate $VBR \
 -c:a $AUDIO_ENCODER -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p \
 -f flv $YOUTUBE_URL/$YOUTUBE_KEY
```

- `-fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 50000` is for ending the output when the shortest input ends, but now both inputs loop indefinitely and you don't want your stream to just stop. So I removed these options.
- Fixed your `-bufsize` and added `-maxrate` to enable VBV which is recommended for streaming. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64490957/) for some general recommendations for that ubiquitous script.
- Removed `-threads`. Let the encoder auto choose the optimal value.

Comment: btw I'm also trying to loop through a set of audio tracks defined in a text file. I have replaced `-i $AUDIO_SOURCE` with `-f concat -i playlist.txt` . The playlist contains a couple of songs. Result: it plays the two songs but then it doesn't loop. Do you know if there is a way to loop through multiple tracks?

Comment: @Claus Should be asked as a new question (at [su] as [so] is supposed to be for programming questions and it might get closed here).

Comment: Written a new one as suggested. Would you be so kind to have a look at it? https://superuser.com/questions/1605604/ffmpeg-looping-stream-of-multiple-files